# Why doesn't 'using' have a catch block?

Tags: c#, language-features, using, using-statement

I understand the point of "using" is to guarantee that the Dispose method of the object will be called.  But how should an exception within a "using" statement be handled?  If there is an exception, I need to wrap my "using" statement in a try catch.  For example:

Lets say there is an exception created in the creation of the object inside the using parameter

```
 try
 {
    // Exception in using parameter
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("LippertTheLeopard"))
    {
       connection.Open();
    }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {

 }
```

Or an Exception within the using scope

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
 {
    try
    {
       connection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
 }
```

It seems like if I already need to handle an exception with a try catch, that maybe I should just handle the disposing of the object as well.  In this case the "using" statement doesn't seem to help me out at all. How do I properly handle an exception with "using" statement? Is there a better approach to this that I'm missing?

```
 SqlConnection connection2 = null;
 try
 {
    connection2 = new SqlConnection("z");
    connection2.Open();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {

 }
 finally
 {
    IDisposable disp = connection2 as IDisposable;
    if (disp != null)
    {
       disp.Dispose();
    }
 }
```

Could the "using" keyword syntax be a little more sugary...

It sure would be nice to have this:

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
 {
    connection.Open();
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
   // What went wrong? Well at least connection is Disposed
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had places where this would be useful.  But more often, when I want to do this it turns out that the problem is in my design; I'm trying to handle the exception in the wrong place.

Instead, I need to allow it to go up to the next level — handle it in the function that called this code, rather than right there.

Comment: +1 This is a great point.  The exception probably should be handled up at the next level.

Answer (score 27):

Because you would be 'hiding' extra functionality inside an unrelated keyword.

However you could always write it this way

```
using (...) try
{
}
catch (...)
{
}
```

And this way the line represents your intentions -- a using statement that is also a try

Comment: That's a short and clean way to do it.

Comment: Nice, that does seem to handle any errors inside the using, although it doesnt cover the exception in the using parameter.  Good to know though

Comment: Gave you your 10th vote for a badge here instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636384/is-it-more-important-to-get-the-problem-done-or-to-write-programs-that-are-easy-t/636448#636448

Comment: Ok, after thinking about this, this is the same as my second example.

Comment: Indeed, but much less verbose.  It looks like it actually fits rather than something that was hacked together.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: Thank you very much, it's always great to hear positive feedback from a higher ranking member like yourself :)

Comment: Rep hardly == skill or expertise, but I appreciate the sentiment. ;)

Answer (score 12):

`using` Has nothing to do with error handling.  It's shorthand for "call Dispose when you leave this block."  Your second code example is perfectly acceptable... why mess with what works?

Comment: The point of the question is, why does using not have an optional catch block. It's more rhetorical unless you work at Microsoft.

Comment: I wouldn't do the 2nd example. imo it's an example of handling an error at the wrong level.  Let it 'bubble up' to the calling function.

Comment: @Joel agreed in the larger scope of things, that's the way I'd do it if you had a reason to do any error handling at that level.

Comment: Well, why doesn't `if` or `while` has an optional `catch` block? A better question is, why should it? `catch` goes together with `try`, like `else` goes together with `if`.

Answer (score 8):

The using block is just syntactic sugar for a try-finally block.  If you need a catch clause, just use a try-catch-finally:

```
SqlConnection connection;
try 
{
    connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.Open();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // handle
}
finally 
{
    if (connection != null)
    {
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Yes, this is more code than your theoretical "using-catch"; I judge the language developers didn't consider this a very high priority, and I can't say I've ever felt its loss.

Comment: You will exit the using statement block when an exception is thrown so a try/catch is better imo.

Comment: @ChadNC: apparently you don't understand `using` - it protects you from exceptions and will dispose the object anyway.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting idea, but it would make the following kinda confusing:

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
 {
     connection.Open();
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
     // Is connection valid? Is cmd valid?  how would you tell?
     // if the ctor of either throw do I get here?
 }
```

Comment: Your example isn't valid. "Stacked" using statements aren't a language feature. Your code is equivalent to nesting the second using inside of the block of the first using. This is no different than writing two if-statements back to back without curly braces.

Comment: If you'd want to catch each exception individually you could nest the using blocks. I actually like the OP's idea even though I'm sure they'll never implement it in the language. Not useful enough, and potentially confusing.

Comment: @bytenik: that's irrelevant.  This code could still confuse people.  It doesn't matter that it's not a special feature.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing concerns in my opinion. Resource management (i.e. disposale of objects) is completely separated from exception handling. The one-to-one mapping that you describe in your question is just a very special case. Usually exception handling will not happen in the same place as the using scope ends. Or you might have multiple try-catch regions inside a using block. Or ...

Comment: the purpose of a finally block is to make sure resources are cleaned up. in a case of using { try {} catch {} finally {} } the using becomes redundant

Comment: Yes, but why use `finally`? In most cases, wrapping `try/catch` inside `using` is clearer _and_ shorter still.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use example #1 and #2 combined. The reason is your using statement could read a file, for instance, and throw an exception (i.e File Not Found). If you don't catch it, then you have an unhandled exception. Putting the try catch block inside the using block will only catch exceptions that occur after the using statement has executed. A combination of your example one and two is best IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the "using" statement is to ensure that some type of cleanup operation will occur when execution exits a block of code, regardless of whether that exit is via fall-through, an exception, or `return`.  When the block exits via any of those means, it will call `Dispose` on the parameter of `using`.  The block exists, in some sense, for the benefit of whatever is being specified as the `using` parameter, and in general that thing won't care why the block was exited.

There are a couple of unusual cases for which provisions might be helpful; their level of additional utility would be well below that provided by having `using` in the first place (though arguably better than some other features the implementers see fit to provide):

(1) There is a very common pattern in constructors or factories of objects which encapsulate other `IDisposable` objects; if the constructor or factory exits via an exception, the encapsulated objects should be `Dispose`d, but if it exits via `return` they should not.  Presently, such behavior must be implemented via `try`/`catch`, or by combining `try`/`finally` with a flag, but it would IMHO be helpful if there were either a variation of `using` which would only call `Dispose` when it exited via exception, or else a `keep using` statement which would null out the temporary employed by the `using` statement to hold the object which needed disposal (since `using` cannot be preceded by an identifier, such a feature could be added in a manner somewhat analogous to `yield return`).

(2) In some cases, it would be helpful if the `finally` keyword extended to accept an `Exception` argument; it would hold the exception which caused the guarded clause to exit (if any), or `null` if the guarded clause exits normally (via return or fall-through), and if the `using` block could make use of `interface IDisposeExOnly {void DisposeEx(Exception ex);}` and `Interface IDisposeEx : IDisposable, IDisposableExOnly {}` (at compile-time, selected `DisposeEx()` if implemented, or `Dispose()` otherwise).  This could allow transaction-based objects to safely support auto-commit (i.e. perform the commit if the passed-in exception is `null`, or roll-back if non-null) and would also allow for improved logging in situations where `Dispose` fails as a consequence of a problem within the guarded clause (the proper thing would be for `Dispose` to throw an exception which encapsulates both the exception that was pending when it was called, and the exception that occurred as a consequence, but there's presently no clean way to do that).

I don't know if Microsoft will ever add such features; the first, and the first part of the second, would be handled entirely at the language level.  The latter part of the second would be at the Framework level.